# Why is typeid behaving differently for references and pointers?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, typeid, typeinfo

Basically what I am wondering is why typeid does not return the typeinfo of the derived type if given a pointer to the derived type.

Example:

If having:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual void foo() {
      std::cout << "This is base speaking" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    void foo() override {
      std::cout << "This is derived speaking" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The following:

```
Derived obj;
Base& ref = obj;
Base* ptr = &obj;
std::cout << typeid(obj).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(ref).name() << std::endl;
std::cout << typeid(ptr).name() << std::endl;
```

Would result in:

```
7Derived
7Derived
P4Base
```

While this:

```
obj.foo();
ref.foo();
ptr->foo();
```

Would result in:

```
This is derived speaking
This is derived speaking
This is derived speaking
```

My guess would be Base* is a type in itself, namely pointer to Base which is not polymorphic and hence statically determined. The reason why the call to *foo* results in the derived version is because of the dereferencing (->). Even if I'm right, I still find it somewhat confusing, since the object pointed to by *ptr* is actually *Derived*.

Comment: you are asking about the type of the pointer, not the type of the pointee.